# How to nest type casting in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, types, casting

I have a json object containing nested dictionaries which I'm trying to parse into swift:

```
{
    "ambientLightColor" : [100.0, 200.0, 300.0],

    "lights" : {
        "light1" : {"position" : [ 5, 5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.0,0.7,0.3]},
        "light2" : {"position" : [-5, 5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.8,0.2,0.1]},
        "light3" : {"position" : [ 0,-5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.3,0.3,0.9]}
    }  
}
```

Since the root object is a dictionary with keys as strings I cast it to such to begin with, as done in the example here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

```
 if let scene = sceneJSON as? [String: Any] {

    if let ambientRGB = scene["ambientLightColor"] as? [f1] {
        ambientLightColor = f3(ambientRGB[0],ambientRGB[1],ambientRGB[2])
    }

    if let lights = scene["lights"] as? [String: Any] {
        for (lightName, properties) in lights {
            let position = properties["position"]
            let direction = properties["direction"]
            let color = properties["color"]
            self.lights.append(Light(position: f3(position[0], position[1], position[2]), direction: f3(direction[0], direction[1], direction[2]), color: f3(color[0], color[1], color[2])))
        }
    }

}
```

As the root dictionary values are first cast as 'Any' they must then be cast to a more usable type when using the entry. This is simple enough for the first entry where I use if let ... as? [f1] to cast the dictionary value [100.0, 200.0, 300.0] to an array of single floats before using them to create a float3 (I'm not sure how to directly cast to float3 from an array of floats but this is not important).

The second case is a little harder, since it again contains another nested dictionary, though I don't want to use if let for each individual element, rather I'd like to use a for loop as shown above. Now I know I must also cast the properties dictionary value from Any type to a dictionary of form [String: [f1]].

I have tried casting it within the first dictionary cast:

```
    if let lights = scene["lights"] as? [String: [String: [f1]] {
        for (lightName, properties) in lights {
            let position = properties["position"]
            let direction = properties["direction"]
            let color = properties["color"]
            self.lights.append(Light(position: f3(position[0], position[1], position[2]), direction: f3(direction[0], direction[1], direction[2]), color: f3(color[0], color[1], color[2])))
        }
```

This gives me an error of [f1] being optional, and when I run it also doesn't find any json objects matching this type.

I have also tried

```
    if let lights = scene["lights"] as? [String: [String: Any] {
        for (lightName, properties) in lights {
            let position = properties["position"] as! [f1]
            let direction = properties["direction"] as! [f1]
            let color = properties["color"] as! [f1]
            self.lights.append(Light(position: f3(position[0], position[1], position[2]), direction: f3(direction[0], direction[1], direction[2]), color: f3(color[0], color[1], color[2])))
        }
```

Though this gives me any error about not being able to bridge NSNumber to float which is a pain to fix when they're in an array.

I've also tried

```
    if let lights = scene["lights"] as? [String: Any] {
        for case let (lightName, properties as? [String:[f1]]) in lights {
            let position = properties["position"]
            let direction = properties["direction"]
            let color = properties["color"]
            self.lights.append(Light(position: f3(position[0], position[1], position[2]), direction: f3(direction[0], direction[1], direction[2]), color: f3(color[0], color[1], color[2])))
        }
```

Which seems like it would be a nice way to write the solution but swift won't accept the type casting within the dictionary pair parentheses.

Would much appreciate a nice concise way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What's `f1` and `f3`? Where are they defined?

Comment: Consider using [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) or at least some library like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). The manual option is a real pain.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica apologies, they are typealiases of Float and SIMD3<Float>

Comment: @Yonat Codable seems a slightly better solution, though I don't think there's any way to account for varying parameters present in the object, because the structs have well defined attributes, rather than being able to select only from those present. I have had a quick look at SwiftyJSON and I think it's probably most suitable. Thanks!

Comment: " any way to account for varying parameters present in the object, because the structs have well defined attributes, rather than being able to select only from those present" could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Your `Codable` struct can have optional members, eg: `var color: SIMD<Float>?`

Comment: @Yonat This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That blog post is 4 years old. JSON parsing in Swift is totally different since Codable was introduced.

Assuming `f` and `f3` are type aliases for `Float` and `SIMD3<Float>`, respectively, then you could just use:

```
import Foundation
import simd
let json = """
{
    "ambientLightColor" : [100.0, 200.0, 300.0],

    "lights" : {
        "light1" : {"position" : [ 5, 5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.0,0.7,0.3]},
        "light2" : {"position" : [-5, 5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.8,0.2,0.1]},
        "light3" : {"position" : [ 0,-5, 0], "direction" : [0,0,0], "color" : [0.3,0.3,0.9]}
    }  
}
"""

struct Light: Codable {
    let position: SIMD3<Float>
    let direction: SIMD3<Float>
    let color: SIMD3<Float>
}

struct Scene: Codable {
    let ambientLightColor: SIMD3<Float>
    let lights: [String: Light]
}

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let scene = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Scene.self, from: jsonData)
print(scene)
```

Comment: Yep seems this is a good option, I was indeed hoping for a way to only decode certain properties but it seems optionals will allow this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having can be circumvented by iterating on the keys, instead of using the for (key, value) flavour. Here's food for thought. Also, as for the NSNumber/Float problem, I found that casting as a [Double] and mapping to a [Float] worked fine, where casting as a [Float] failed.

```
for key in lights.keys {
    let lightDict = lights[key] as! [String: Any]
    let position = lightDict["position"] as! [Double]
    let direction = lightDict["direction"] as! [Double]
    let color = lightDict["color"] as! [Double]

    print(position)
    print(direction)
    print(color)

    let floats = color.map { Float($0) }
    print(floats)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The main issue was indeed the casting from NSNumber to Float. The iterator was also causing some strange problems relating to the use of the Float initialiser needing more context, so this solves that also. However, I do like clarity and conciseness in my code so I will likely explore the other options unless the devs improve the serialisation. Cheers